# Android - onClick in adapter not working

Tags: android, adapter

Scenario:

User clicks a button and a row(adapter) is added. The user inputs a value and clicks on a button which is generated. The value would be computed and displayed in an edit text.

Problem: The value is not computed nor is it being displayed in the edit text. What am I doing wrong?

custom_list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">  

<LinearLayout
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
android:gravity="center">

<EditText
android:id="@+id/name"
android:layout_width="125dp" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:hint="Name"
android:maxLength="10"
/>

<EditText
android:id="@+id/price"
android:layout_width="80dp" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:hint="Price"
android:inputType="numberDecimal"
android:maxLength="5"
/>

<Button
android:id="@+id/calculate"
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Calculate"
/>

</LinearLayout>

<EditText
android:id="@+id/result"
android:layout_width="150dp" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
android:editable="false" 
android:cursorVisible="false"
android:text="$0.00"
/>
```

main.java    `<<EDITTED>>`

```
public class AdvancedBillSplitter extends Activity{

ArrayList<String> noteList = new ArrayList<String>();
FancyAdapter aa = null;

Button calculate;
//EditText price;
EditText result;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ListView myListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.noteList);
    aa = new FancyAdapter();

    myListView.setAdapter(aa);

    myListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                 int position, long arg3) {
           EditText price = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.price);
           price = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.price);
           double price1 = Double.parseDouble(price.getText().toString());
           double total = price1 *1.1;
           String resultPrice = Double.toString(total);
           result.setText(resultPrice);
           System.out.println(total);

        }
    });
    aa.notifyDataSetChanged();


    Button btnSimple = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSimple);        

    btnSimple.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            noteList.add(0, "");
            aa.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    });        

}

class FancyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>
{
    Button calculate;
    EditText price;
    EditText result;

    FancyAdapter()
    {
        super(AdvancedBillSplitter.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, noteList);
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View row = convertView;     

        if(row == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_list_item, null);
        }

        return (row);
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 5):

simple addition,

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/calculate"
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
android:text="Calculate"
/>
```

its not catching click event because the list has 2 items which are focussable (The list item and the button) , so now thats an Ambiguous situation. so make the button not focussable. it still catches click events.

Comment: I would edit, but it's not above six characters so I cant.  Focusable is spelled wrong here  - "focussable" - so a simple copy/paste wont work.  Should be android:focusable="false"

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you want to use the recommended method [**setOnItemClickListener()**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setOnItemClickListener%28android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener%29) on the `ListView` instead - I guess it is a bad style to set the listeners directly within the adapter.

Comment: So I do a myListView.setOnItemClickListener() in my main?

Comment: I have included that in the code but its still not working. I have editted my question with the updated codes I have

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't

> EditText price = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.price);

be

> EditText price = (EditText)view1.findViewById(R.id.price);

(Note the view1)

Also, you have the `findViewById()` line twice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Handler to update your view.
Like this:

```
Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
@Override

    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
        case 0:
            aa.notifyDataSetChanged();
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }

    }};

btnSimple.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        noteList.add(0, "");
        mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()`, You can use the `new OnItemClickListener()` which imports `import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;`

**Dont have the click listener for the inflated layout and also for the parent layout(ie for listview). If you have the inflated layout's click listener then control will directly transfer there.**

```
myListViewmyListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int position, long arg3) {
                  price = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.price);
                  double price1 = Double.parseDouble(price.getText().toString());
                  double total = price1 *1.1;
                  String resultPrice = Double.toString(total);
                  result.setText(resultPrice);

            }
        });
```

I think this might give you some idea. And once the data has changed try to call the `notifyDataSetChanged()` method to refresh the view.

All the best.

```
class FancyAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
Button calculate;
EditText price;
EditText result;



    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return noteList.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;     

            if(row == null)
            {
                LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_list_item, null);
            }

            return (row);
    }

}
```

Comment: I have changed my codes accordingly but it still isn't working. It is not picking up the data from edit text.

Comment: try doing  `price = (EditText) arg1.findViewById(R.id.price);` then check if it is identifing the `edittext`

Comment: @Hend : Is the price is returning null to you?

Comment: I did a System.out.println(result); but there was not print outs in the logcat. The click ain't being registered or listened.

Comment: @Hend : Pls try to add the FancyAdapter class which is added in my answer and check for the result.